pre-render error happens when rendering fetch function with revalidate
Next 14.1
I am trying to create a page that shows the fetched data. But when I add { next: { revalidate: 60 } } instead of {cache: "no-store"}, it returns errors on building. Building works fine with {cache: "no-store"}. How do I fix  this issue?
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST}/api/getData`, {
    cache: "no-store", 
  });

  const data = await res.json();

  return data;
}

export default async function HomePage() {
  const result= await getData();

errors when building with revalidate
⚠ Using edge runtime on a page currently disables static ge   Generating static pages (19/36) [=== ]
TypeError: fetch failed

